# What is the best way of retrieving data from TimescaleDB when using C#?

Tags: c#, postgresql, time-series, npgsql, timescaledb

I have a .NET Core web application that needs to read data from TimescaleDB. The data represents different aggregations performed on pretty complex measurements that are coming from multiple machines. My question is what is the best approach to retrieve this data? Judging from their documentation for other languages (they do not have a C# quick start yet) I have seen that they are using something which is similar to ADO.Net way of working. Is this the only way, are there any 3rd parties that handle this scenarion?

Comment: You can use anything what works with PotgreSQL and allows to write SQL queries. I guess there are tutorials for calling PostgreSQL from C#.

Comment: Yeah, I know I have currently tried working with both EFCore and Npgsql comamnds directly. What I was wondering is if there might be other ways which I haven't found out yet and might work better for my case.

Comment: @CiprianNazarie Have you found any solutions?

Comment: In the meantime they have released an official tutorial for C# integration [link](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/quick-start/dotnet/#procedure-connecting-net-to-timescaledb) . For my POC I have chosen to use Npgsql since I did not want any Primary Key constraints that EF enforces.